# using json data in my gridview array

Tags: java, android, json, gridview

I am messing around with my own gallery app that loads images (thumbs and full size) from a webserver. I have my image info returned from a database and encoded as json data.

```
{"id":["1","2","3"],"name":["Dragon","Butterfly","Tattoo"],"thumb":["thm_polaroid.jpg","thm_default.jpg","thm_enhanced-buzz-9667-1270841394-4.jpg"],"path":["polaroid.jpg","default.jpg","enhanced-buzz-9667-1270841394-4.jpg"]}
```

I am using the developer.android.com [hello gridview](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) tutorial as my reference. They are using a url referencing local images.

MY QUESTIONS.

1. Should I parse my json data into separate arrays since I will be using all of the data at some point in my app or should I keep it all together?
2. how can I replace the static image array found below with my thumbnail images?

Static Image array

```
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
        R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
        R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
        R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
        R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to definea class that has member variables id,name,thumb,path.

```
public class foo{
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String thumb;
    public String path;
}
```

Then just parse your arrays into an ArrayList of this bject type.

```
ArrayList<foo> myFooArray = new ArrayList<foo>();
```

You can call the add method on the myFooArray to append a foo object:

```
myFooArray.add(new foo());
```

To answer the second part of your question you would reference the thumb member of the object in your array

`mThumbIds[position]`  becomes `myFooArray[position].thumb`

of course you will need to load the image from file rather than resource, you should easily be able to find an example of this but for a clue you can use something like `setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(myFooArray[position].thumb);`